# Can't execute commands when connected to AWS SFTP Transfer server

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp

First of all, I created a simple bucket in S3.

After that, I created a server in AWS SFTP Transfer service https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/.

Then I created a new user inside AWS SFTP for test purposes and attached role that has `AdministratorAccess` policy to it.

Finally, I tried to connect with sftp terminal command. It connect successfully. But when I am on the server I can't do any of sftp commands. For example:

```
sftp> dir
Couldn't read directory: Failure
```

Why I can't execute any SFTP command on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. Please refer to the article [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-amazon-s3/) for details.

But most likely it is wrong set up of a role. Be aware that you have to not only set up the role with access to s3 bucket. For example like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::data-transfer-inbound"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::data-transfer-inbound/jeff/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You also have to set up trusted entity (principal) for the role to assume it. In this case the principal should be `transfer.amazonaws.com`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "transfer.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the role you can put the above in on the tab "Trust relationships".